# Subprocess OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, linux, memory, subprocess, fork

Hello I am trying to run my app client/server in which client sends strings to the server and server takes strings and it creates a cloudtag (image.png) and copies it to a html file (to a web page) in a python script.

I have an error in the line in which I copy the image file to the html directory:

```
query = 'sudo cp imagen.png /var/www/html'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(query))
```

I dont know why I can only send two strings to the server. Then the error comes up when I send the third one from the client to the server and the console says:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__ errread,errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1223, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Does anybody know which is the relation between the subprocess module and the memory and how can I solve it? Thank you!!